# Finding average age in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find the average age of column `created_at` using Eloquent `avg` function. I can get the average date, but now I think I just need to get today's date and subtract today's date by the average age. However, I am having issues with that. I am calling the function this is all happening in an Axios call, but it's returning a `500` error.

Here is the function that is being called:

```
public function ajaxRequest() {
    $ticketCount = array();
    $campusNames = array();

    $campuses = Campus::where('TechID', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $date = date();

    foreach($campuses as $campus) {
        $campusNames[] = $campus->CampusName;

        $tickets = Ticket::where('CampusID', $campus->id)->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(5))->where('TicketStatus','New Issue')->avg('created_at');

        $averageAge = date_diff($tickets, $date );

        $ticketCount[] = $tickets;
    }

    return(['ticketCount' => $ticketCount,
            'campusNames' => $campusNames]);
}
```

Also, is going this route the better option, or is it better to get the age of every ticket, add the age variable to an array, then average the array?

**EDIT**

This is the average age array:

```
["20190112075852.0000",
 "20190112075900.0000",
 "20190112075904.0000"]
```

Here is the log:

```
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'date() expects ...', 'C:\\\\Users\\\\grosal...', 65, Array)
#1 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController.php(65): date()
#2 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController->ajaxRequest()
#3 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('ajaxRequest', Array)
#5 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(219): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\PagesController), 'ajaxRequest')
#6 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#7 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(682): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#8 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#11 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#13 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#14 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#17 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#20 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#22 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#23 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#29 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(684): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(659): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(625): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#34 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(614): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#54 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 C:\\Users\\grosales\\Documents\\project-falcon\\Project-Falcon\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\Users\\\\grosal...')
#57 {main}
"}
```

I've added parameters to the date variable, but still same result sadly

```
public function ajaxRequest() {
    $ticketCount = array();
    $campusNames = array();

    $campuses = Campus::where('TechID', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    $timezone = date_default_timezone_get();
   $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

    foreach($campuses as $campus) {
        $campusNames[] = $campus->CampusName;

        $tickets = Ticket::where('CampusID', $campus->id)->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->subDays(5))->where('TicketStatus','New Issue')->avg('created_at');

        $averageAge = date_diff($tickets, $date);


        $ticketCount[] = $tickets;
    }

    return(['ticketCount' => $ticketCount,
            'campusNames' => $campusNames]);
}
```

Comment: Every 500 error should be accompanied by a useful error message, either on the page if you've got `APP_DEBUG=true`, or in the logs.

Comment: Initial glance, you're missing the format for `date()`, so it's probably throwing the error there. There's also the other part where `date_diff` requires a DateTime object.

Comment: I have added what the average age array `tickets` returns and log if it's helpful. Thank you

Comment: PHP's `date()` function needs parameters! https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I have added the parameters, but still not able to figure this out. Thank you though

Comment: `date_diff()` expects two `DateTime` objects as it's arguments, you're passing in an array and a string

Comment: @RMcLeod you are correct, but I decided to go a completely different route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three tips for you:

1. Use eager loading to load the tickets relationship, or else you will end up with an [`n+1` queries issue](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-n-1-problem) in your code.
2. Define an [accessor method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to make the age calculation easier.
3. Use the Collection's built-in [average method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-average) to calculate average age.

Something like this could work:

```php
class Campus extends Model
{
    public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Tickets::class);
    }
}

class Tickets extends Model
{
    public function getAgeAttribute()
    {
        return $this->created_at->diffInDays(Carbon::now());
    }
}

public function getTicketAverageAgePerCampus()
{
    $campuses = Campus::with(['tickets' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('TicketStatus', 'New Issue');
    }]);

    $averageTicketAges = [];

    foreach ($campuses as $campus) {
        $averageTicketAges[$campus->id] = $campus->tickets->average('age');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will read over the documentation again to better understand everything you pointed out. I am assuming I would just need to do something like `$averageAge = $tickets->averageTicketAges`?

Comment: In the example function `getTicketAverageAgePerCampus` I have shown how to compile a list of average ticket ages in an array, indexed by campus ID. You just need to return `$averageTicketAges` from that function for instance.

Comment: To get the average ticket age for the tickets belonging to one campus, you just do: `$campus->tickets->average('age');`.

Comment: If you want an average for ALL campuses, just do `Tickets::all()->average('age')`.